# HDR camera and stabilized video on Galaxy S5 neo

Tags: root-access, camera, samsung-galaxy-s-5, video-recording

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 neo (SM-G903F). The phone runs original Android 5.1 (only rooted). The camera app does support neither HDR photos nor stabilized video recording.

Is there a way how to do do HDR photos and stabilized video recording? Maybe some 3rd party application that could do it? I would prefer single app for both HDR photography and stabilized video. Post-processing is not an option for me in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Open Camera](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.sourceforge.opencamera/). It's free also [on playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera). Open Camera is based on camera2 API and supports 4K recording (if you're hardware support it too).

Comment: Could you please include a link – and elaborate a little on how this solves the issue?

Comment: You can search it on playstore, it's the only one app camera without ads contained inside

Comment: That's not how this site works, Zulfahmi (see: [How do I write a good answer](/help/how-to-answer) in our help). Answers must be self-contained, not forcing the user to perform another search on another site. Also it should include all details to answer the question. So please include a link and the necessary details.

Comment: I know that but it's on playstore. Impossible to copy the link over here.

Comment: That's actually pretty easy (just done it for you; guess you're working from your phone and just use the playstore app; using a web browser it's not an issue). As is clicking the [edit] link and adding some context – which is your task now :) PS: as for "the only camera app without ads", I could [name a few more](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera) – though Open Camera is clearly my favorite, too.

Comment: I got downvote for my answer, really.?

Comment: Looks like. Not mine, though – but most likely someone who shared my thoughts and thinks you should do that [edit]. Does *Open Camera* support HDR photos and *stabilized* video recording? I've tried neither of the two, so I cannot tell. But that's what OP asked for.